# What is 'this' keyword in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

```
Item {
    id: test
    Component.onCompleted: console.log("this is ", this, test)
}
```

The above code output shows the same pointer to the Item, so what is `this` keyword in QML?
Is that the pointer of the nearest QML component and can be used same as `id`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`this` is an attribute that refers to the QML object but its scope is local and does not reach the scope of the children.

Instead:

> object can be referred by its `id` from anywhere within the scope of the component in which it is declared. Therefore, an identification value must always be unique within its component scope.

for example:
In the following code it is observed that the this within the second Item refers to item2 not to item1.

```
Item{
    id: item1
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("item1")
        console.log(this === item1)
        console.log(this === item2)
    }

    Item{
        id: item2
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("item2")
            console.log(this === item1)
            console.log(this === item2)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
qml: item1
qml: true
qml: false
qml: item2
qml: false
qml: true
```

Comment: BTW I can not find Qt doc provide the explanation about `this` keyword. Have you seen any doc about that?

Comment: @Jiu Actually there is no information in Qt, that is a characteristic of javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: They do mention it, but wrong: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html => Last subsection. However the piece of their example that *should not work* works fine. You just need to see that the function `mouseAreaClicked` is found - so it needs to be in the files root node or you need to refer to it as `parent.mouseAreaClicked` from the `MouseArea`s.