# In QML, could a component property be the component itself?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to assing a Component itself to one of its property, and then passing that property to a function inside an external file (`import "Scripts.js" as Scripts`)

The first thing that came to my mind was (in my opinion) the most obvious method:

```js
//MyComponent.qml

Item {
    id: comp
    
    // property var target: comp
    // doesn't work either
    property var target: this

    ...

    onActiveFocusChanged: {
        // Scripts.foo(this)
        // and Scripts.foo(tf)
        // don't work either
        if(this.activeFocus) {
            Scripts.foo(target)
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work (the window crashes after giving activeFocus to the Component).

So, I assigned undefined to the target as default:

```js
...
property var target: undefined
...
```

and then assigned the Component itself when declared:

```js
MyComponent {
    id: myComponent
    ...
    target: this
    // target: myComponent
    // also works
    ...
}
```

When the activeFocus is triggered, everything works fine. Can someone tell me why / what I'm doing wrong?

It's impossible to assing to a component property the component itself?

And why it's not impossible to do this after declared?

Comment: you can use `id` property as a pointer to the instance, I don't really  sure that `this` works as you expect here.

Comment: @folibis thank you for the comment. I've already tried using the `id` instead of the `this` keyword, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: How about declaring `Component.onCompleted: target = this;;` in your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` keyword has special meaning in Javascript and can change it's meaning depending on context. Since you declared it as `target: this` you made it property bind so that every change to `this` will trigger a new value in `target`. To work around that problem, you can ensure that you capture `this` exactly once with:

```
// MyComponent.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {
    property Item target
    Component.onCompleted: target = this
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your code clean of imperative code, you can make use of `parent` in the following way:

```
// MyComponent.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Item {
    readonly property alias target: internal.target
    Item {
        id: internal
        property Item target: parent
    }
}
```

In the above, `internal` is clearly a subitem of `Item` and therefore, there can only be one meaning for `parent` which is your original item itself.

Comment: Never I thought about that every change to the Component will trigger a new value in target.. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As folibis already commented you should use `id`s instead of `this` keyword. Have a look at the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292515/525038).

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello Component")

    function foo(parameter) { console.log(parameter) }

    component MyComponent : Item {
        id: component

        property var target: component

        Component.onCompleted: {
            root.foo(component.target)
            root.foo(component)
        }
    }

    MyComponent {}
    MyComponent { target: root }
}
```

This works without an issue.

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    id: root
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello Component")

    function foo(parameter) { console.log(parameter) }

    component MyComponent : Item {
        id: component

        property var target: component

        onActiveFocusChanged: {
            if(component.activeFocus)
                root.foo(component.target)
        }
    }

    MyComponent { id: test }

    Component.onCompleted: test.forceActiveFocus()
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I've already tried using the `id` instead of the `this` keyword, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Edit your question to show what did not work. My example shows you how to use `id` to do something like you was trying to do. At least from what I can understand from the snippets you have shared.

Comment: Inside the Component, giving to the property the `id` or the `this` keyword as default, nothing works (`property var target: this` / `property var target: comp //the id`). But, if I assign the value `this` or the `id` (comp) to the property when I declare the Component, everything works.

Comment: I've added another example which works without any issue. I don't get your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve and what I've tried to code... but it doesn't work. I guess that the problem is located inside the function, I'll check better. Thank you for your time!